# memtest86 : unexpected interrupt - halting CPU0

Tags: memory, memtest

trying to troubleshoot my notebook Acer 5600, I ran Memtest86 with the two 512Mo RAM, with one and the other one, but I have the same error each time : [image: here is a screen photo]

The Windows XP installed crash on connection screen, but I reinstall a corporate Windows XP and run it severals hours without any problem. Linux installation still run fine.

Actually, is there any problem with my notebook? With RAM or CPU? How can I really check it?

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): *"Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with the CPU.  Or perhaps the motherboard.  I would probably stress it with Prime95 to make sure, use the small profile.  Do you have any BSoD minidumps?

Comment: No, no BSOD occur on this PC